# oozie scheduling for c# application

Tags: c#, hadoop, oozie

I am using oozie-4.1.0 in windows. I want to schedule an c# application through oozie. As far as I know oozie only supports java,pig,hive.
can any one tell me whether there is an support to schedule c# application

Answer (score 0):

Oozie does not support c#, as far as I know, but has shell action:
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/DG_ShellActionExtension.html
This could be a work-a-round - if you start your c# application via a shell action.